# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts using SSH Tunnel

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

Connection.Open() Error: MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

I've already tried multiples times with many codes here in Stack, but i still receiveing this error,it's using a jumpbox to connect into a ec2, if i change the string connection to localhost, i get the local database, not the production,some people had said to do that, using the forwardPort but it didn't solve.

links that i've tried:

["Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" when connecting to MySQL database via SSH.NET tunnel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370107/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-when-connecting-to-mysql)

[Connection to MySQL from .NET using SSH.NET Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603982/connection-to-mysql-from-net-using-ssh-net-library#32605335)

[How to connect to mysql from C# over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806799/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-c-sharp-over-ssh)

[How to forward ports over an SSH tunnel using Granados with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394391/how-to-forward-ports-over-an-ssh-tunnel-using-granados-with-c-sharp)

and others.

```
static bool isFirstTimeSSH()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Verificando se é a primeira vez \n");            
            
                     

            string _privateKeyPath = @"MyKeyPath";
            string _privateKeyPassPhrase = "";
            string _host = "MyDbHost";
            
            var privateKeyStream = new PrivateKeyFile(_privateKeyPath, _privateKeyPassPhrase);

            var sshHostAddress = _host;
            var sshPort = 22;
            var sshUser = "MyUserSSH";

            var ci = new PrivateKeyConnectionInfo(sshHostAddress, port: Convert.ToInt32(sshPort), username: sshUser, privateKeyStream);         
            using (var client = new SshClient(ci)) // establishing ssh connection to server where MySql is hosted
            {
                client.Connect();
                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1","MyDbHost", 3306);
                    client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
                    portForwarded.Start();                

                    Console.WriteLine("Verificando se é a primeira vez \n");

                    string mySQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MySQLConnectionString");
                    string connStr =
    string.Format(
        "Server = {0};Port = {1};Database = database;Uid = MyDbUser;Pwd = MyDbPass;SslMode=none;default command timeout=10;Connection Timeout=3;MinimumPoolSize=20;maximumpoolsize=500",
        portForwarded.BoundHost, portForwarded.BoundPort);

                    //Aqui você substitui pelos seus dados            
                    var connection = new MySqlConnection(mySQLConnectionString);
                    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM transactions;";
                        MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        dt.Load(dataReader);
                        int numberOfTransactions = 0;

                        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                numberOfTransactions = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                            }
                        }
                        if (numberOfTransactions < 20)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                            connection.Close();
                        client.Disconnect();
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client cannot be reached...");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change some things and in the end I managed to access it through this code:

```
var databaseServerIp = "Insert MySQLHostName here";
             var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", databaseServerIp, 3306);
```